# How to stop Adobe Flashplayer from opening update pop-ups

Tags: macos, updates, popups, adobe-flash

It's the AFP Install Manager that keeps opening up...

[image]

Long story short Adobe Flashplayer keeps opening pop-ups telling me I need to update it on my MacBook.

However, no matter how many times I follow the update steps, it continues to open and disrupt my workflow. It's starting to really get on my nerves haha

Is there a way to disable automatic updates? Or does anyone know why when I update, it still says I need to update?

Thanks,
Cam.

Comment: The popup is malicious.  Adobe Flash does not generate popups asking you to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a virus/trojan known as [Shlayer](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/osxshlayer-new-mac-malware-comes-out-of-its-shell/).
Most malware removal can find it these days - try Malwarebytes, or Intego from the above link.

Comment: Ahhh shite.. I best get fixing it then 

Answer (score 2):

Those update popups are likely **not** from Adobe, but from a web site **trying to install malware** masquerading as a legitimate application.

However, if you do not *need* Adobe Flash, then remove it from your browser. [Adobe has deprecated Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash), and with HTML5 in common use, it is rarely used any longer.

Comment: Thanks, that is something that crossed my mind too. I think I only needed it for some old web applications I was using a while ago. I think I'll get rid of it to be safe.

Comment: I've now included a screen capture in my question if you'd like to view it

Comment: @Cam Getting rid of Adobe Flash won't get rid of whatever malware was actually installed; you need to scan & clean your Mac.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna try what @Tetsujin recommended ^^